# UML Class Diagram of an Object Return and Declaration

Tags: java, uml

How would you model the declaration of y and the getY function in a UML Class Diagram, language coded in Java.

```
public class MyProgram {
 private Double y = 5;

 double getY() { return new Double(y); }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [IBM UML Basics](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/sep04/bell/)

The UML representation of a class is a rectangle containing three compartments stacked vertically, as shown in Figure.

The top compartment shows the class's name.

The middle compartment lists the class's attributes.

The bottom compartment lists the class's operations.

When drawing a class element on a class diagram, you must use the top compartment, and the bottom two compartments *are optional*. (The bottom two would be unnecessary on a diagram depicting a higher level of detail in which the purpose is to show only the relationship between the classifiers.) Figure 1 shows an airline flight modeled as a UML class. As we can see, the name is Flight, and in the middle compartment we see that the `Flight` class has three attributes: `flightNumber`, `departureTime`, and `flightDuration`. In the bottom compartment we see that the Flight class has two operations: `delayFlight` and `getArrivalTime`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I understand the concepts of UML at a basic level but not sure how to represent the code I typed.

Comment: If you are asking about the default value of y then I have provided another example. But if you are asking regarding the logic inside getY in which it creates a new Double then keep in mind that class diagram are not for representing logic, they just depict the structure and are incapable of depicting logic.

Comment: Yeah that answers it.